# A Lower Bound for the sum of the element orders in a cyclic group of order n

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let G be a cyclic group of order n, where n is odd.  What is the infimum of the average of the sum of the element orders in G?

Comment: I don't understand the question. $n = \sum_{d \vert n}\phi(d) d$.

Comment: I don't undertand the comment. I'd assume the phi is Euler totient but then the equality is false. 

Comment: Maybe Andrea meant to write $n = \sum_{d|n} \phi (d)$?


Comment: @Patricia Hersh: Maybe, but then it does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: @quid: good point.  Is it easy to see that there is an infinite sequence of odd numbers $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < \dots $ where this average keeps decreasing in value?  For instance, the odd primes would not work.

Comment: What in the name of Reilly is an average of a sum?

Comment: A sum' is a sum that remembers the number of summands. The average of a sum' is the sum divided by the number of summands. 

Comment: @quid: technically, one could use $\sum \phi (d) \le \sum d\phi (d)$, but obviously your answer is far better.

Comment: @Patricia Hersh: I like that argument.   

Comment: @Steven so by "the average of a sum" he means "the mean"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. I meant to write $n = \sum_{d \vert} \phi(d)$.

Answer (score 8):

As (indirectly) commented by Andrea the quantity in question is 
$$\alpha(n)=\frac{1}{n}  \sum_{d \mid n} d \varphi(d) $$
so that in particular $\varphi(n)$ is always a lower bound. 
And the actual infimum is $1$, attained for $1$.

However, there are various interesting question related to this and (perhaps) since the 'average' was not quite clear in the start actually something else could be meant.

In view of the above it is natural to  further scale down by $\varphi(n)$ and study the resulting quantity $\alpha(n)/\varphi(n)$. 
Its limit inferior is $1$ while the limit superior is $\zeta(2) \zeta(3) / \zeta(6)$.

Or, one could study $\frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \le x} \alpha(n)$. 
This would then by asymptotic to $\frac{\zeta(3)}{2 \zeta(2)} x$.

These results and more information can be found in a paper by [von Zur Gathen et al. (JNTB, 2004)](http://jtnb.cedram.org/cedram-bin/article/JTNB_2004__16_1_107_0.pdf)